# TableLayout enforce text in one line

Tags: android, textview, android-tablelayout

I have a little problem with my table layout.

I have two columns

column1 | column 2

The column1 content is static and indicates a property e.g. "locations", "products".
The second column is populated using an adapter.

My problem is that the text view breaks the word in column1. I want the word of column1 to be displayed in exactly one line (enforce that the line does not break). And the size of the second column has to adapt.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/tl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*"

    >


     <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

          <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="products"
            android:padding="5dp"

          />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Branche"
            android:padding="5dp"/>


    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I tried to set
android:singleLine="true"
However the device (S3) only shows the first few letters and ...

I also tried to set a layout_weight. However I was not able to fix this issue.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tl"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*">


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="products"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newID"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:text="ancheBrrancheBraeBrancheBrancheBrancheBrancheBrancheBrancheBrancheBrancheBranche"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

If you use a `layout_weight` attribute, you should remeber about the fact that `layout_width` must be set with `0dp` (in this case of course).